# How to remove all the dictionaries from an NSmutablearray which contains a particular key?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an IPhone application in which I have an `NSMutableArray` of dictionaries. When selecting each row of the table, I am deleting the dictionaries by using

```
if (indexPath.row <[self.newmessagearrays count])
{
     [messagearrays removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

I have a scenario in which I want to remove all the dictionaries in which my "from id" key is the same, when the row is tapped. I tried like this, but with no effect:

```
 NSPredicate * pr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userid == %@",fromidstring];
[messagearrays filterUsingPredicate:pr];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can filter the array in place using `NSPredicate`:

```
NSPredicate * pr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"containsKey == SOME_KEY"];
[messageArrays filterUsingPredicate:pr];
```

**Update**

In response to edit/clarification:

```
NSPredicate * pr = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:
  ^(id dictionary, NSDictionary * bindings) {
    return (BOOL)![[dictionary objectForKey:@"fromid"] isEqual:@"190"];
}];
[messageArrays filterUsingPredicate:pr];
```

Comment: i need to remove all the dictionaries where the fromid key in the dictionary is a particular value,like say 190...

Comment: that is not being the case in your answer i suspect

Comment: @hacker no, that wasn't clear to me (in the original question). the code above will just remove all dictionaries in the array which contain a value (*any* value) for the key `SOME_KEY`. the predicate you describe in the clarification could be written: `NSPredicate * pr = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary * bindings){return (BOOL)![[evaluatedObject objectForKey:@"fromid"] isEqual:@"190"];}];`

Answer (score 0):

Array keeps objects at some index, dictionary keeps object and keys
so your algorithm should be like this

Get object(dictionary) from array one by one using loop, check that your dictionary has that specific key.
if yes, remove that object from array using function `removeObjectAtIndex`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableIndexSet *discardedItems = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
NSDictionary *item;
NSUInteger index = 0;

for (item in yourArrayOfNSDictionaries) {
    if ([dictionary objectForKey:theKeyYouWantToCheckFor] != nil) [discardedItems addIndex:index];
    index++;
}

[originalArrayOfItems removeObjectsAtIndexes:discardedItems];
```